# Prolog. Combining predicates

Tags: prolog

I have to make a `predicate/2` which takes a list of "correct" numbers as validation, and a function which needs to be validated. The numbers in the function (represented as `number(X)`) has to be the same as the numbers in the validation list, to become "true".

I have no problem making two seperate `predicates/1` which give the correct answer when the list is "hard-coded" in the library, but I can for the god of mine not combine these.

I have this so far:

```
number(X) :- member(X, [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

This gives the correct result as when i ask for for example `and(number(2),number(4))`, it says yes, and `and(number(2),number(6))` gives no.

But now I have to do `predicate/2`, which takes the list as the first argument. 
Can anyone help/give any hint?

```
predicate(ValidationList, Function) :- ????
```

Comment: not sure to unserstand... `and(number(2),number(4))` and `and(number(2),number(6))` are examples of functions to validate? Or what do you mean (can you show some examples?) with "function which needs to be validated"? Anyway... can you show your `predicate/1`?

Comment: yes, these are exaples of functions to be validated. It's about propositional formulas. If "and(number(1),number(2))" is to be correct, then the validation list has to contain the numbers 1 and 2. That's why "number(X) :- member(X, [1,2,3,4,5])" works.
My problem is to define a predicate, so that I can afterwards type for example "predicate([1,3,5,7] , or(number(1),number(2)))." And it checks if 1 and 2 are a part of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `call` predicate:

```
and(X,Y) :- call(X), call(Y).
or(X,Y) :- call(X); call(Y).

predicate(List, Function) :-
    Function =.. [P,X,Y],
    call(P, member(X, List), member(Y, List)).
```

For example:

```
?- predicate([1,2,3], and(1,3)).
true.

?- predicate([1,2,3], and(1,4)).
false.

?- predicate([1,2,3], or(1,4)).
true.

?- predicate([1,2,3], or(4,5)).
false.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
How does that check if the formula is a member of my validation list?

Comment: Check my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be

```
predicate(ValList, and(X, Y)) :-
    predicate(ValList, X),
    predicate(ValList, Y).

predicate(ValList, or(X, Y)) :-
      predicate(ValList, X)
    ; predicate(ValList, Y).

predicate(ValList, number(X)) :-
    member(X, ValList).
```